# conversion to GMT giving problems during DST

Tags: java

I am facing a problem in our existing application where time entered by an employee (from his org/store using time clock application) is first converted to GMT and then stored in the DB. And for displaying back, the time in GMT is converted back to store local time zone and displayed. In most of the cases this works fine but not when the time zone moves to DST and vice versa.

Let me be more specific. Suppose the standard time zone of the store is GMT-8 and the employee punches at 08:00 AM in the morning, so the time is converted to GMT which gives 16:00 and then is stored in the DB. 
The conversion process first converts this 08:00 AM to store local time which somehow gives 
17:00 CET and then this 17:00 CET is converted to GMT which gives 16:00 CET.

But if we take an example of 31 March when the DST happens where 02:00 AM becomes 03:00 AM. Suppose the emplyoee punches at 18:00 (on 30 March) it returns me 04:00 AM CEST during the first conversion to local and then when i convert this to GMT it gives 03:00 CEST. So while converting it back this gives 19:00 which is not correct. 
The design says the local times are converted to UTC and then stored in the DB but if it still UTC then it should store 02:00 AM and not 03:00 AM because GMT/UTC does not have DST.

The code used to do the conversion is:

**Step 1**

```
final Date localPunchDateTime = R3ValConverter.convertFromTimeZone(teData.m_dtTm,  
                                               TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));
```

**Step 2**

```
teData.m_dtTm = R3ValConverter.convertToGMT( localPunchDateTime );
```

**R3ValConverter.java**

```
public static Date convertFromTimeZone(final Date dtSrc, final TimeZone tzSrc)
    {

        final SISDateTime dtTmTemp = new SISDateTime(dtSrc, TimeZone.getDefault());
        final SISDateTime dtTmSrc = new SISDateTime( dtTmTemp.getYear(), dtTmTemp.getMonth(), 
                                                     dtTmTemp.getDate(), dtTmTemp.getHour(), 
                                                     dtTmTemp.getMinute(), dtTmTemp.getSecond(), 
                                                     tzSrc );

        return dtTmSrc.toDate();                                                       
    }
```

**SISDateTime**

```
GregorianCalendar m_cal;

public SISDateTime(Date dt, TimeZone tz) throws SISDateTimeException
    {

        m_cal = new GregorianCalendar(tz);
        m_cal.setTime(dt);
        resetMillis();
    }
```

The other SISDateTime method is also using the same GregorianCalendar.

I would really appreciate any help in this regard. I am assuming here that we have some problem here in the first step but dont know any good solution to it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store UTC + current offset in seconds from Local time to UTC in the db.
So if you want to preserve the local time, you always need a pair (Utc time, offset)

You use then `TimezoneWithOffsetFromGMT` (or simmiliar named)

Comment: we have the offset which is 8 during standard time and 7 during DST but if i take my example where we have punch at 18:00 and store it as 03:00 AM (after conversion to GMT) then during the reconversion it does not work because 03:00 - 8 (offset) gives 19:00..

Comment: you should not store it as 03:AM , you should store it as long value utc milliseconds or seconds since 1.1.1970 (unix time)

Comment: between 18:00 and 3 AM there are 9 hours, not 8!

Comment: Hi Alex, Many thanks for your inputs. but how do i get the UTC milliseconds before making a date object. because if i make a date object then it automatically changes the 02:00 AM to 03:00 AM and then if i get the milliseconds using getTime() method then it still gives value corresponding to 03:00 AM and not 02:00 AM. Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: new Date().getTimeStamp() is a long value in UTC milliseconds since 1.1.1970 (see javadoc on Date) Store this long value, together with current TimeZone difference to UTC. before using any toString() method you must be sure that the TimeZone of your PC is correctly set, or you must explicitly specify the TimezOne on SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Further tipp, never use the Date object as paramter, use long timeStampUtcMillis instead. Date is not immutable, you accidentally can change the value of a Date object and all other parts of your program which share a reference to this Date receive the unwanted change

Comment: What is teData.m_dtTm ? Is that timeStamp in millis UTC? yes, then name it timeStampUTC, no then there is your problem